# How do i use GenyMotion with Appcelerator Studio?

Tags: appcelerator, genymotion

The appcelerator team have released a new version of their IDE, which was called Titanium and is now called - for reasons that baffle me - Appcelerator Studio.

(The bafflement is because now it's almost impossible to google search for solutions for the new IDE because of the naming... )

Does anyone have step by step process for getting Appcelerator Studio to recognise and debug with GenyMotion?

Imagine that the genymotion has been installed in c:\GLoc and the Oracle VirtualBox was installed to c:\OLoc

Answer (score 1):

If you have already [installed](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Installing+Genymotion#InstallingGenymotion-Windows) Genymotion  , then you can open up in Titanium studio and find emulators as below :

[image]

Detailed doc on downloading , installation and configuring Genymotion , please refer doc available [here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Installing+Genymotion#InstallingGenymotion-Installation)

When you are running test you might need to differentiate for specific environments.

To detect which emulator you are running your code in, you can use Ti.Platform.manufacturer, which returns unknown on Android Virtual Devices, but Genymotion on Genymotion emulators.

[Reference](https://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/03/how-to-detect-and-run-code-specific-to-genymotion-emulators/)

> If you are running Titanium Studio 3.3.0 , then target SDK of app
>   should be 3.3.0 or greater.

**Try refreshing device in emulators , if they are still invisible try opening Terminal Window.**

Find Detailed instruction [here](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/07/new-in-titanium-studio-3-3-0-run-in-genymotion/)